# How do I install Pdftk on my server?

Tags: php, linux, pdftk

I am using a Linux Server and am trying to install Pdftk, but I am problems trying to figure out what exactly to do.

I found the following documentation on how to install it, but they refer mostly to installing it on the local Windows machine.

They are:
http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/07/29/installing-pdftk-php/

http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/#packages

Can someone help me unserstand exactly what files I need to place where on my server so I can refer to pdftk?

Comment: What distribution and version?

Comment: The first instructions you linked to do contain linux instructions... First step would probably be unzipping the tarball into a directory in `/var/www/` (or similar, depends)...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pdftk is a version of iText which has been converted from Java to c++ and rebuilt with a command-line bridge for easy access from PHP applications.

To build pdftk on Redhat / CentOS please follow the below instructions.

```
ssh [server to install pdftk on]
```

Now that we are in the server we need to create the directories to store pdftk.

```
cd /
sudo mkdir extra
cd extra
sudo mkdir src
cd src
sudo wget http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/pdftk-1.41.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf pdftk-1.41.tar.gz
cd pdftk-1.41/pdftk
```

Now we need to install the gcj libraries.

```
sudo yum install java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-devel.i386
```

The gcc-c++ library doesn't get installed with the gcj package so we will install it now, so we don't get an error halfway through the compile process.

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

If you compile the application right now you will receive a warning that tmpnam is dangerous to use and you should use mkstemp.

```
sudo vi report.cc
```

Run this from inside VI to do a search and replace for the tmpnam method.

```
:%s/tmpnam(/mkstemp(/g
```

Press escape and save the changes with

```
:wq!
```

Now that we have all the packages installed, we are going to start compiling pdftk-1.41

from /extra/src/pdftk-1.41/pdftk run the following command

```
sudo make -f Makefile.RedHat
```

This will kick off the build process for compiling and converting the java file to c++.  This could take SEVERAL minutes to convert iText to c++.  Go grab yourself a margarita from our new margarita machine in the break room :).

Now with the pdftk file created we will want to copy it to the /bin directory so that we can run it from anywhere.

```
sudo cp pdftk /usr/local/bin
```

Let's make sure the build was successful and run

```
pdftk --version
```

Comment: i have followed your instructions to install pdftk ...and pdftk --version runs okay

Comment: but i cant make it run through php..why?

Comment: I am trying to follow your directions to install PDFTK on my VPS. I get to `sudo yum install java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-devel.i386`. Once I execute that command, I get this a a response: `Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
imhbase                   100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
serverdensity             100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
not using ftp, http[s], or file for repos, skipping - 4 is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet
Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: update
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: update`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed instructions.
I needed to take one additional step:
Edit the Makefile.Redhat file, and change `export VERSUFF=` to `export VERSUFF=""`. Prior to that make would just drop out without doing any work.

Comment: Works for version 1.45 on Centos 6.3 if you change wget to http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit//pdftk-1.45-src.zip

Comment: For CentOS there is version in extra repository. Explained here: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/anyone-know-how-install-pdftk-cpanel-centos-189881.html

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, things are different now. CentOS 6 is stepping out and pdftk can only support [CentOS 5/6](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk-on-redhat-or-centos/). GCJ on CentOS 7 is removed, so installing from source is not easy too. But we have docker now:

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install -y https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk-2.02-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Then build with `docker build . -t pdftk` and run as:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/data --workdir /data pdftk pdftk ./input.pdf output ./output.pdf
```

The example above can repair a pdf file missing a dozen of KB of data if you are lucky.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, there is [pdftk-java](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk): A port of the original GCJ-based PDFtk to Java, which is [currently on the way to the repositories](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?like=pdftk-java-3.3.1) for Fedora 33+ and EPEL 7+ (latter for CentOS, RHEL or Rocky), allowing `yum install pdftk-java` to succeed (once the package reached the stable repositories).

Edit: The pdftk-java package is in the stable repositories since yesterday, 2021-10-29.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @rsc, pdftk-java will be available for Rocky Linux, but currently (2021.10.28), still cannot install it via `yum`.

Fortunately, there is a built command for x86_64 GNU/Linux systems, **which does not require any runtime dependencies**. So we can use it as follows

```sh
# the version number might be updated, check https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk
wget https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/jobs/1527259632/artifacts/raw/build/native-image/pdftk
chmod +x pdftk
./pdftk ...
```

It works well in the server with the following system info,

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Rocky
Description:    Rocky Linux release 8.4 (Green Obsidian)
Release:    8.4
Codename:   GreenObsidian
```

Comment: The pdftk-java package is in the stable repositories since yesterday, 2021-10-29. Given it receives updates via a regular `dnf update`, the RPM package should be preferred over static builds being manually downloaded.