# Run pdftk by php on linux centos

Tags: php, centos, pdftk

I would like to run pdftk on my webserver. It's a Linux Centos with PHP 5.3.2.

When I connect it by commande line I do

```
pdftk --version
```

It's OK

```
pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf
```

It's OK.

Now, I do this by php :

```
exec(pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf)
```

It isn't OK. Why?? I search about the link of file, but it looks OK.

This doesn't work too :

```
exec(pdftk --version)
```

I install pdftk with this [How do I install Pdftk on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146766/how-do-i-install-pdftk-on-my-server)

So what's wrong??

Thank for your help!

Comment: are you using `exec(pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf)` or `exec("pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf")`? Note the quotes around the command. Also, what error message do you get, what does it mean "it does not work"?

Comment: Of course I use quotes. When I write this message I forgot to put them. Thanks for that. Also, the PDF is not generated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this issue before. Assuming that you're wrapping your commands string in quotes (as gioele noted), the issue may be that you need to [set your path](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/USE_oview/Setting_your_path.html) when running the system command. Try this:

```
$command = "pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf";
system("PATH=\$PATH:/usr/bin/ && $command",$response);
if ($response===FALSE){
   //there was an error, handle it
}
```

(I've added a little response handling there as well). If that doesn't work, check to see what path you should use (it will depend on where you installed PDFTK).

I believe you can also get the same result by using `putenv("PATH=" .[your path]);` and I've used `system()` here, but `exec()` should be affected in the same way

Comment: When I echo $response, I haven't any thing. Where can I see where pdftk it installed?

Comment: My pdftk is here /usr/local/bin

Comment: Have you tried it setting `system("PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/bin/ && $command",$response);`?

Comment: Yes! It's work. 

    system("PATH=/usr/local/bin && pdftk A=p1-9.pdf cat A1 output p1.pdf");