# passthru not working in pdftk

Tags: php, linux, ssh, pdftk

I am new so ssh and terminal commands
I am installed pdftk on my web server (Linus Cent-Os dedicated virtual server) using the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146766/how-do-i-install-pdftk-on-my-server).

Although got initially problems because all of my experience was GUI, but somehow following the instructions, I succeeded in installing pdftk

Now when I type command `whereis pdftk`

the response is

> pdftk :/usr/bin/pdftk /usr/local/bin/pdftk/

when I was following the instructiion, the last step was to copy the folder to /usr/local/bin/ that went successful. now when I issue the command
 `pdftk --version`
it runs successfully, returning the version info.

in my php, when I try to use this with

> `passthru('/usr/local/bin/pdftk --version')`

nothis is displayed

can somebody guide me what Can I do?

Comment: If pdftk writes the version data to STDERR instead of STDOUT, you won't see it - passthru doesn't capture stderr usually. Try doing a `pdftk --version 2>&1` to force stderr into stdout.

Comment: by addin ' 2>&1 ' in php code returns sh: /usr/bin/pdftk: No such file or directory, all though i have told you the output of ' whereis pdftk '

Comment: using powerpannel, i have seen that the file pdftk actually exists on the location

Comment: Well, if the exec call can't find it, then perhaps consider that powerpanel is lying.

Comment: using whereis pdftk command, using power panel, going to the location step by step (cd /usr/local/bin/) evrything shws that pdftk is there..

Comment: only passthru() is not workng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does it work when you leave out local and just do:

```
<?php echo passthru('/usr/bin/pdftk --version'); ?>
```

tried it on my server, /usr/bin/ does display version data but /user/local/bin doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I had to set

```
safe_mode = Off
```

in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, otherwise I only got

> sh: /pdftk: No such file or directory.